# ID Reference in CSS not working but Class reference is working

Tags: html, css

So I'm working on making a website to post my Unity games and I came across a problem I've never had before.

When I use an ID as a reference in my CSS, it doesn't work but when I use a Class reference, it does work.

Here is my HTML & CSS:

```css
#notes {
  padding: 20px;
}

.boxes {
  background-color: #dee3e2;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.boxes h1 {
  color: #0c7b93;
}

body {
  background-color: #de7119;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxes" id="notes">
  <h1>Notes:</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>Color Scheme is Bad.</li>
    <li>Code is Messy.</li>
    <li>My Games Still Suck.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please show which code doesn't work?

Comment: To be honest, you picked my curiosity so I tried to switch the CSS properties from `.boxes` to `#notes` in the snippet and it worked fine, I cannot reproduce your issue (or I do not understand correctly)...

Comment: Dev tools shows that the padding from the #notes ID is being applied to the div. Am I misunderstanding the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not sure why this is happening. Everything I know about CSS would say this should work.

However, it's a good practice to not use IDs as CSS selectors. The reason why is outlined here pretty well: https://github.com/CSSLint/csslint/wiki/Disallow-ids-in-selectors

Sorry if this isn't much of an answer, but I would highly recommend using classes over IDs for targeting elements for CSS